# Ubuntu server 16.04 can't ping outside IP's or domains or do updates

Tags: networking, server, ssh, dns, webserver

I moved my server to my work and setup everything. 
Changed the Internal IP to a new on and also changed the static IP to a new one. 
 When I do a ifconfig the new IP address/default-gateway/subnet all show as correctly. 
 The problem is I can't access the server through any pc on the network, can't ping any domain or external IP, can't do a `apt-get` anything, I added new rules to the firewall I am using now(**mikrotike** **router/firwall**) allowed port 80 and also pointed the new static IP to my domain company used(onlydomains.com). I also restarted apache2, the actual server and even router. 
 I can only ping internal IP's only.

I checked out many posts and google and was told to check:

> /etc/resolve.conf 
>  /etc/network/interfaces 
>  /etc/gai.conf
> (uncomment. precedence::ffff:0:0/96 100) to get apt-get working 
> also flush ip setting

When the server was by my home everything worked perfectly. I could access the website, ssh into the server from anywhere and so on.

I am so confused and don't know what needs to be done in order to fix it.

*If this has been solved somewhere please direct me there.
Thanks

**Update:**

`ip route` output:

```
default via 192.168.1.254 dev eno1 onlink <br>
192.168.11.0/24 dev eno1   proto  kernel  scope  link  src  192.168.11.199
```

---

changes made in /etc/network/interfaces
= I changed the network/broadcast/gateway as these were outside the range of the IP Address.

---

Can reach the server via SSH and can ping the default gateway however I can't ping any domain only IP's on the network. Also can't do any apt-get's.

---

dig google.com

======

```
; <<>> Dig 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> google.com <br>
;; global options: +cmd <br>
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached <br>
```

/etc/resolv.conf

========

```
nameserver 41.xxx.0.36 <br>
nameserver 41.xxx.0.37 <br>
search website.com <br>

dig google.com @8.8.8.8 <br>
```

===

```
;<<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> google.com @8.8.8.8 <br>
;; global options: +cmd <br>
;; Got answer: <br>
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 17942 <br>
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1 <br>

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION: <br>
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512 <br>
;; QUESTION SECTION: <br>
;google.com         IN A <br>

;; ANSWER SECTION: <br>
google.com.     192     IN A 216.58.223.46 <br>

;; QUERY time: 104 msec <br>
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8) <br>
;; WHEN: Fri Apr 13 10:22:42 SAST 2018 <br>
;; MSG SIZE rcvd: 55
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
default via 192.168.1.254 dev eno1 onlink 
192.168.11.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.11.199
```

So your local network is 192.168.11.0/24 by the looks of it, and your IP address on eno1 is 192.168.11.199.

But your default gateway is 192.168.1.254.

This will not work. Your local gateway is **outside** your local network, so you have no means of contacting it.

You have to check your network settings in `/etc/network/interfaces`, so that the configuration is consistent. When that's done verify that you're able to ping your default gateway.

In addition, it seems that your defined DNS servers do not work. Some suggested servers would be Cloudflare's, at 1.1.1.1 or Google's at 8.8.8.8.

In `/etc/network/interfaces` you will have a line like

```
dns-nameservers 41...
```

Change this to `dns-nameservers 1.1.1.1` for instance, and either reboot, or edit `/etc/resolv.conf` and replace the current `nameserver 41...` lines with `nameserver 1.1.1.1`.

Verify that you're able to `ping google.com`

Comment: I can now ping the default gateway and can reach the server via SSH, however I cannot do any apt-get's

Comment: You probably have to set DNS server as well.

Comment: How would I do that? I am still a noob when it comes to this. I have set the dns-nameserver in the /etc/network/interfaces. And set it in the /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: I have tried a solution from another post where it was said to try ifdown eno1 && sudo ifup eno1 but that made no difference. Does it take time for things to sink in before that command would work maybe?

Comment: What is the content of `/etc/resolv.conf`? What happens if you try `dig google.com @8.8.8.8`? What happens if you try `dig google.com`? Edit your question with the outputs, and ping me in a message :)

Comment: have put the output of the dig google.com and the /etc/resolv.conf file

Comment: What about `dig google.com @8.8.8.8`?

Comment: updated question

Comment: Ok, so DNS servers you are using are not working. Change to use for instance 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8 as DNS servers. I will update my answer

Comment: when i changed the dns to 8.8.8.8 it started to work. I can use apt-get and install anything. Much appreciated.