# Ubuntu 18.04 can't ping outside IPs or domains

Tags: networking, server, dns, firewall

I recently created a cloud Ubuntu 18.04 server and I am unable to ping outside IPs. My network (from my understanding) is managed by netplan.

**Attempts to ping or curl**

```
$ ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.23.110) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 5125ms

$ curl google.com
<hangs>
$ ping -c 4 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3076ms
```

**ip route**

```
default via 135.xxx.48.1 dev ens3 proto dhcp src 135.xxx.48.217 metric 100
135.xxx.48.0/22 dev ens3 proto kernel scope link src 135.xxx.48.217
135.xxx.48.1 dev ens3 proto dhcp scope link src 135.xxx.48.217 metric 100
```

**ip addr**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fa:16:3e:31:bc:f8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 135.xxx.48.217/22 brd 135.171.51.255 scope global ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:fe31:bcf8/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**route -n**

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         135.xxx.48.1    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens3
135.xxx.48.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 ens3
135.xxx.48.1    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 ens3
```

**iptables -L**

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Similar questions and answers online often refer to using `ifdown` or `ifup` but these programs are not installed, and my network is instead being managed by `netplan`, as can be seen below.

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# ifupdown has been replaced by netplan(5) on this system.  See
# /etc/netplan for current configuration.
# To re-enable ifupdown on this system, you can run:
#    sudo apt install ifupdown
```

Contents of `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`:

```
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        ens3:
            dhcp4: true
            match:
                macaddress: fa:16:3e:31:bc:f8
            set-name: ens3
```

I looked at [Ubuntu server 16.04 can't ping outside IP's or domains or do updates](https://askubuntu.com/q/1024304/1081385) (among various other questions), but the answers were not applicable to my netplan system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix my connectivity problems, all I had to do was set and export the `HTTP_PROXY`, `HTTPS_PROXY`, and `FTP_PROXY` environment variables in my `/etc/profile` to the appropriate values for my company's corporate proxies.